# Why is get_template_directory_uri() not including a slash with Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

This is the code on my website which is producing the error.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tothewebsite.comget_template_directory_uri/js/jquery.js?ver=1"></script>
```

the code inside my functions.php folder looks like this.

```
function WM_Scripts()
{

    wp_register_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.js', '',1,true  );
    wp_register_script('bootstrapjs',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrapjs' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'WM_Scripts' )
```

I don't understand why get_template_directory_uri isn't including a slash before the website name ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep `get_template_directory_uri` in `<?php ?>` tag. You can call your script like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Because the second code block is my only reference to the jquery.

Comment: You don't need to do `wp_register_script` in function because you can directly enqueue script like `wp_enqueue_script`